# How to communicate with smart contract using python?

Tags: remix, python

I have developed a smart contract on remix IDE and now I want to communicate with it using python. What python libraries can I use ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [web3py](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

And if you need to compile contracts - use [solc](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.21/installing-solidity.html).

Answer (score 0):

Or not specifically python but you can use [Etheratom](https://github.com/0mkara/etheratom) to deploy and interact with your smart contract.

Comment: This is a comment. Not suitable for an answer.

Comment: I wanted to add as a comment, didnt have enough reputation tho.